# how to change only the color of the chip clicked in react from a dynamically created array of chips

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When a users drags and drops an excel or csv file on me I am dynamically creating material-ui chips from the columns of that file. I am showing them the columns and allowing the user to click the column they want then I build list for them based on the data that is associated with that column. Everything is working correctly except for when the user clicks the chip I want the chip to turn green and add a checkmark to indicate that is the chip selected. They can select many chips so if they select another one I want that chip to turn green. They can also hit the x and deselect the chip at which point i want the chip to go back to the original color and check to go away.

```
  return (
  <div>
    {
      props.dropdownkeys.map((value, index) => (
        <Chip label={value}
          icon={<CheckIcon key={index} id={`check_${value}`} color='primary' visibility={clickedChip ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}/>}
          key={index}
          onClick={() => addChip(value, index)}
          onDelete={() => deselectChip(value, index)}
          size='small'
          id={`chip_${value}`}
          ref={setChipRef}
          className={clickedChip ? classes.chipSelected : classes.chip }
        />
      ))
    }
  </div>
);
```

this is my dynamically created chips i am trying to trigger based off a useState hook to change clickedchip

```
 const [clickedChip, setClickedChip] = useState(false);
```

this is my addchip functionality

```
function addChip(value: number | string, index: number) {
  debugger;
  const chipClicked = getClickedChip(index);

  if (chipClicked !== null) {
    // chipClicked[0].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    // (chipClicked[0].firstChild as HTMLElement).style.color = 'red';
    // (chipClicked[0].firstChild as HTMLElement).attributes[6].value = 'visible';
  }

  const getCols = props.excelDocumentObj.filter((column) => {
    if (column[value] !== undefined) {return column[value];} else { return null;}
  }); 
  if (props.storeString !== '') {
    props.setStoreString(',');
  }

  const rowLen = getCols.length;
  for (const [i, storeNum] of getCols.entries()) {
    if(typeof storeNum[value] === 'number') {
      if(rowLen !== i + 1) {
        props.setStoreString(`${storeNum[value] },`);
      }
      else {
        props.setStoreString(`${storeNum[value]}`);
      }
    }
  }
  creatorStore.handleStoreListFromExcel(props.storeString);
}
```

the problem i ma having I am changing all of the chips in the renderer not the selected chip like I want. I do not want to access the chip through the dom because basically I was told not to do this on my pull request. I am new to react so I am having issues doing this simple task and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

i fixed this instead of using a boolean value i set an active index value like this

```
const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(-1);
```

then in my render I changed it to this

```
return (
  <div>
    {
      props.dropdownkeys.map((value, index) => (
        <Chip label={value}
          icon={<CheckIcon key={index} id={`check_${value}`} color='primary' visibility={index === activeIndex ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}/>}
          key={index}
          onClick={() => addChip(value, index)}
          onDelete={() => deselectChip(value, index)}
          size='small'
          id={`chip_${value}`}
          ref={setChipRef}
          className={index === activeIndex ? classes.chipSelected : classes.chip }
        />
      ))
    }
  </div>
);
```

then in my addclick I called the function to update

```
function addChip(value: number | string, index: number) {
  debugger;
 setClickedChip(index, true);

  const getCols = props.excelDocumentObj.filter((column) => {
    if (column[value] !== undefined) {return column[value];} else { return null;}
  }); 
  if (props.storeString !== '') {
    props.setStoreString(',');
  }

  const rowLen = getCols.length;
  for (const [i, storeNum] of getCols.entries()) {
    if(typeof storeNum[value] === 'number') {
      if(rowLen !== i + 1) {
        props.setStoreString(`${storeNum[value] },`);
      }
      else {
        props.setStoreString(`${storeNum[value]}`);
      }
    }
  }
  creatorStore.handleStoreListFromExcel(props.storeString);
}
```

which in turn calls this function

```
 function setClickedChip(index: number, value: boolean) {
  if (value) {
    setActiveIndex(index);
  }
  else {
    setActiveIndex(-1);
  }
}
```

then my deslect is this

```
function deselectChip(value: number | string, index: number) {
  setClickedChip(index, false);
  let deleteString = props.storeString;
  const getCols = props.excelDocumentObj.filter((column) => {
    if (column[value] !== undefined) {return column[value];} else {return null;}
  });
  for(const column of getCols) {
    deleteString = removeValue(deleteString, column[value], ',');
  }
  props.deleteFromStoreString(deleteString);
  creatorStore.handleStoreListFromExcel(props.storeString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the easiest way to solve this problem would be to add a property to the props.dropdownkeys called "selected". This would be a Boolean. Note you may have to add this wherever “props.dropdownkeys” is defined in the parent component.

Then your code would look like the following:

```
    return (
  <div>
    {
      props.dropdownkeys.map((value, index) => (
        <Chip label={value}
          icon={<CheckIcon key={index} id={`check_${value}`} color='primary' visibility={value.selected ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}/>}
          key={index}
          onClick={() => addChip(value, index)}
          onDelete={() => deselectChip(value, index)}
          size='small'
          id={`chip_${value}`}
          ref={setChipRef}
          className={value.selected ? classes.chipSelected : classes.chip }
        />
      ))
    }
  </div>
);
```

Note that with this approach you will need to add a function to toggle the selected property in the parent component where you initialized the props.dropdownkeys. Assuming you call it toggleChip(), you can then call this with the onClick event handler. Something like

```
onClick={() => props.toggleChip(value, index)}
```

You can also change your clickedChip state variable to be an array that is mapped to each chip with values of either true or false.

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical error here. You are using one boolean variable (clickedChip) for all the chips. So, if any one chip is selected, clickedChip becomes true and `className={clickedChip ? classes.chipSelected : classes.chip}` becomes true for all.

You need to know uniquely which chip was selected.

So, what you need to do is:
 - Initially, initialize clickedChip to null
 - In your clickedChip variable, store the unique value (such as some id or key) related to a particular chip only
 - In your className or icon condition, match that particular chip's unique value to the saved value and apply the logic to show green or making icon visible
 - On clicking cross or deselecting, set clickedChip to null

The code will transform something like this (note: I am not exactly aware of the hooks syntax so have explained by setState):

```
state = { clickedChip: null }

setClickedChip = (uniqueChipId) => {
    this.setState({ clickedChip: uniqueChipId }) 
}

render() {
...
  return (
    <div>
      {
        props.dropdownkeys.map((value, index) => (
          <Chip label={value}
            icon={<CheckIcon key={index} id={`check_${value}`} color='primary' visibility={clickedChip === `chip_${value}` ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}/>}
            key={index}
            onClick={() => addChip(value, index)}
            onDelete={() => deselectChip(value, index)}
            size='small'
            id={`chip_${value}`}
            ref={setChipRef}
            className={clickedChip === `chip_${value}` ? classes.chipSelected : classes.chip }
          />
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
...
```

chip_${value} and uniqueChipId are the unique chip Ids

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts/clarifications.

Comment: thank you for your response that is kinda what I did just with the index above, but now what is going on I click one and it changes but when I click on another the first one they clicked on changes back to blue and the other one changes green. I want both of them to be green until they deselect the chip with the x button

Comment: In this case, you need to work on what @chickenjake has written. Inside each object for dropdownkeys, add a variable selected and toggle it to true or false. Another approach can be that in your solution only, you can store all the selected ids in an array(instead of activeIndex or clickedChip) and then check if the corresponding id exists in the array and make it green. Remove the id from the array when user clicks again.